# How to get data from object

Tags: angularjs, json, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["CaseId"]=>
  string(27) "SEAD-NLRC-NCR-11-00002-2016"
}

[
  {
    "Case_ID": "2",
    "Case_Status": "Withdrawn",
    "Case_Reference_Number": "SEAD-NLRC-NCR-11-00002-2016",
    "Case_Date_Filed": "November,24,Thursday,2016 1:30 PM",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Name": "Anak ng diyablo corporation",
    "Requesting_Party_Age": "99",
    "Requesting_Party_Gender": "",
    "Requesting_Party_Address": "sa ilalim ng lupa siyempre",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "09207819920",
    "Requesting_Party_Date_Of_Employment": "30 November, 2016",
    "Requesting_Party_Nature_Of_Work": "nag babantay ng mga maiinit na bato",
    "Requesting_Party_Salary_Rate": "5000",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Name": "angheles junkshop",
    "Responding_Party_Nature_Of_Business": "Construction",
    "Responding_Type_Of_Enterprise": "MICRO (1-9)",
    "Responding_Party_Position": "mercenary naman",
    "Responding_Party_HouseNo": "",
    "Responding_Party_Street": "",
    "Responding_Party_Barangay": "",
    "Responding_Party_ZipCode": "",
    "Responding_Party_City": "",
    "Responding_Party_Contact_Details": "miguelita",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "baklaako@yahoo.com",
    "Case_Holder": "DESK-75034-2016",
    "Notice_Of_Conference": "None",
    "Remarks": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Date": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Time": "Not Set",
    "Joint_Conference_Holder": "DESK-00060-2016",
    "Lawyer_Holder": "DESK-10101-2017"
  }
]
```

How to get the data inside the object in this kind of format.
I'm using AngularJS and I want to call in the `ng-repeat` using `$http.post`.

Answer (score 0):

## Using JavaScript

- using [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "Case_ID": "2",
    "Case_Status": "Withdrawn",
    "Case_Reference_Number": "SEAD-NLRC-NCR-11-00002-2016",
    "Case_Date_Filed": "November,24,Thursday,2016 1:30 PM",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Name": "Anak ng diyablo corporation",
    "Requesting_Party_Age": "99",
    "Requesting_Party_Gender": "",
    "Requesting_Party_Address": "sa ilalim ng lupa siyempre",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "09207819920",
    "Requesting_Party_Date_Of_Employment": "30 November, 2016",
    "Requesting_Party_Nature_Of_Work": "nag babantay ng mga maiinit na bato",
    "Requesting_Party_Salary_Rate": "5000",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Name": "angheles junkshop",
    "Responding_Party_Nature_Of_Business": "Construction",
    "Responding_Type_Of_Enterprise": "MICRO (1-9)",
    "Responding_Party_Position": "mercenary naman",
    "Responding_Party_HouseNo": "",
    "Responding_Party_Street": "",
    "Responding_Party_Barangay": "",
    "Responding_Party_ZipCode": "",
    "Responding_Party_City": "",
    "Responding_Party_Contact_Details": "miguelita",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "baklaako@yahoo.com",
    "Case_Holder": "DESK-75034-2016",
    "Notice_Of_Conference": "None",
    "Remarks": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Date": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Time": "Not Set",
    "Joint_Conference_Holder": "DESK-00060-2016",
    "Lawyer_Holder": "DESK-10101-2017"
  }
];

var res = jsonObj.map(function(item)  {
 return item.Case_ID;
});

console.log(res);
```

- using JavaScript [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [
  {
    "Case_ID": "2",
    "Case_Status": "Withdrawn",
    "Case_Reference_Number": "SEAD-NLRC-NCR-11-00002-2016",
    "Case_Date_Filed": "November,24,Thursday,2016 1:30 PM",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Name": "Anak ng diyablo corporation",
    "Requesting_Party_Age": "99",
    "Requesting_Party_Gender": "",
    "Requesting_Party_Address": "sa ilalim ng lupa siyempre",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "09207819920",
    "Requesting_Party_Date_Of_Employment": "30 November, 2016",
    "Requesting_Party_Nature_Of_Work": "nag babantay ng mga maiinit na bato",
    "Requesting_Party_Salary_Rate": "5000",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Name": "angheles junkshop",
    "Responding_Party_Nature_Of_Business": "Construction",
    "Responding_Type_Of_Enterprise": "MICRO (1-9)",
    "Responding_Party_Position": "mercenary naman",
    "Responding_Party_HouseNo": "",
    "Responding_Party_Street": "",
    "Responding_Party_Barangay": "",
    "Responding_Party_ZipCode": "",
    "Responding_Party_City": "",
    "Responding_Party_Contact_Details": "miguelita",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "baklaako@yahoo.com",
    "Case_Holder": "DESK-75034-2016",
    "Notice_Of_Conference": "None",
    "Remarks": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Date": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Time": "Not Set",
    "Joint_Conference_Holder": "DESK-00060-2016",
    "Lawyer_Holder": "DESK-10101-2017"
  }
];

for(var i in jsonObj) {
 console.log(jsonObj[i].Case_ID);
}
```

## Using AngularJS

- using **`ng-repeat`**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

$scope.jsonObj = [
  {
    "Case_ID": "2",
    "Case_Status": "Withdrawn",
    "Case_Reference_Number": "SEAD-NLRC-NCR-11-00002-2016",
    "Case_Date_Filed": "November,24,Thursday,2016 1:30 PM",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Name": "Anak ng diyablo corporation",
    "Requesting_Party_Age": "99",
    "Requesting_Party_Gender": "",
    "Requesting_Party_Address": "sa ilalim ng lupa siyempre",
    "Requesting_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "09207819920",
    "Requesting_Party_Date_Of_Employment": "30 November, 2016",
    "Requesting_Party_Nature_Of_Work": "nag babantay ng mga maiinit na bato",
    "Requesting_Party_Salary_Rate": "5000",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Name": "angheles junkshop",
    "Responding_Party_Nature_Of_Business": "Construction",
    "Responding_Type_Of_Enterprise": "MICRO (1-9)",
    "Responding_Party_Position": "mercenary naman",
    "Responding_Party_HouseNo": "",
    "Responding_Party_Street": "",
    "Responding_Party_Barangay": "",
    "Responding_Party_ZipCode": "",
    "Responding_Party_City": "",
    "Responding_Party_Contact_Details": "miguelita",
    "Responding_Party_Full_Contact_Info": "baklaako@yahoo.com",
    "Case_Holder": "DESK-75034-2016",
    "Notice_Of_Conference": "None",
    "Remarks": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Date": "Not Set",
    "Remarks_Time": "Not Set",
    "Joint_Conference_Holder": "DESK-00060-2016",
    "Lawyer_Holder": "DESK-10101-2017"
  }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="case in jsonObj">
   Case ID : {{case.Case_ID}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note :** AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a `ng-repeat` directive. This means if you are trying to do the following, you will get an error.

`<div ng-repeat="names in [alpha,alpha]">`

to remove this problem you have to use `track by $index` inside `ng-repeat` directive.

`<div ng-repeat="names in [alpha,alpha] track by $index">`